# bind_param and bind_result is there a difference?

Tags: php, mysqli

I know that is better to bind the parameter instant of using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` but I have no opportunity to use mysqlnd driver because of my Host. So is it safer to use Bind the Parameter instant of `BIND_RESULT`? Here are two examples for what I mean. The easiest way for me would be to do it via `mysql_real_escape_string ()` but that is no longer safe if I understand it correctly, isn't it?

bind_param:

```
<?php 

$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "world"); 

if (!$link)
{
    $error = mysqli_connect_error();
    $errno = mysqli_connect_errno();
    print "$errno: $error\n";
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, Population, Continent FROM Country WHERE Continent=? ORDER BY Name LIMIT 1";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query))
{
    print "Failed to prepare statement\n";
}
else
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $continent);

    $continent_array = array('Europe','Africa','Asia','North America');

    foreach($continent_array as $continent)
    {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
        {
            foreach ($row as $r)
            {
                print "$r ";
            }
            print "\n";
        }
    }
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

And now bind_result:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 150,5";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query)) {

    /* execute statement */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $name, $code);

    /* fetch values */
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $name, $code);
    }

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Note that you can use [mysqli_stmt::get_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) only if _mysqlnd ("MySQL Native Driver")_ is installed. Otherwise you are forced to use [mysqli_stmt::bind_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php), which you can precede with [mysqli_stmt::store_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) if you want _"to buffer the complete result set by the client"_).

Comment: On the other hand, [mysqli::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), [mysqli_stmt::bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and [mysqli_stmt::execute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) can be used in both situations, e.g. if _mysqlnd_ is installed or not.

Comment: Also note that [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) _"was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0"_. Preparing the SQL statements (see my second comment) is the right way to protect your system from [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injections).

Comment: And, at last, as I know: If _mysqlnd_ is installed, in order to fetch all records at once you can use [mysqli_result::fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) after calling [mysqli_stmt::get_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php). Otherwise, e.g. if _mysqlnd_ is not installed, you are forced to work only with [mysqli_stmt::fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php), in order to fetch each record at a time.

Comment: *"is it safer to use Bind the Parameter instant of BIND_RESULT?"* What does that mean? Parameters are what you send to the database. Result is what you get from the database. It has nothing to do with security. Why are you using mysqli at all? Why are you using mysqli without mysqlnd driver? In 2020 it sounds unreasonable that a host would not provide such basic functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big difference as they are for two different parts of the process.

[bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) is for binding variables going INTO the query.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent); // <-- This is for the question marks
```

[bind_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) is to assign variables going OUT of the query

```
$stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM country");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2); // <-- The values from id will be assigned to $col1, and the values from name will be in $col2, inside your loop
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf("%s %s\n", $col1, $col2);
}
```

They can be used together, or not at all. For instance, you might want to process the variables in another way coming out of the query, and the second query I show does not need bind_param at all since there are no parameters to bind.

Comment: That is correct, but unfortunately I cannot insert parameters into the database even like this.

Comment: That would probably be a different question, then. What is the code you're using, and what happens when you try to use it? Make sure you're checking for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) when it fails to find out why it's not working.